# Why I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException while running spark job?

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I am trying to run a spark job using below gcloud command.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster=clusterName \
--class=clazzName \
--jars=gs://abc/def/ghi.jar \
--region=us-central1 \
--files=gs://abc/def/jkl.json \
--properties=spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file=application_dev.json",spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file=application_dev.json",spark.executor.memory=6G,spark.driver.memory=4G,spark.executor.cores=3,spark.executor.instances=4
```

I am getting below error

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found: gs://temp-bucket/f80f8cb3-0358-445e-8ec2-819e4282bfe4/spark-job-history
```

Full stack trace

```
Waiting for job output...
22/09/02 05:30:47 INFO com.polaris.ihub.commons.utils.keymaker.KeymakerApi: ====== Reading App Context ======
22/09/02 05:30:47 INFO com.polaris.ihub.commons.utils.keymaker.KeymakerApi: File to be read from -> gs://abc/def/app_context.txt
22/09/02 05:30:49 INFO org.apache.spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
22/09/02 05:30:49 INFO org.apache.spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
22/09/02 05:30:49 INFO org.apache.spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMasterHeartbeat
22/09/02 05:30:49 INFO org.apache.spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
22/09/02 05:30:49 INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.util.log: Logging initialized @8633ms to org.sparkproject.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
22/09/02 05:30:50 INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server: jetty-9.4.40.v20210413; built: 2021-04-13T20:42:42.668Z; git: someAlphaNumeric1; jvm 1.8.0_322-b06
22/09/02 05:30:50 INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.server.Server: Started @8803ms
22/09/02 05:30:50 INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@2db33feb{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:38111}
22/09/02 05:30:50 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at clusterName-m/someIp:8032
22/09/02 05:30:51 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.AHSProxy: Connecting to Application History server at clusterName-m/someIp:10200
22/09/02 05:30:51 INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
22/09/02 05:30:51 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
22/09/02 05:30:55 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_appID
22/09/02 05:30:56 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at clusterName-m/someIp:8030
22/09/02 05:30:57 ERROR org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found: gs://temp-bucket/f80f8cb3-0358-445e-8ec2-819e4282bfe4/spark-job-history
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getFileStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileWriter.requireLogBaseDirAsDirectory(EventLogFileWriters.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.SingleEventLogFileWriter.start(EventLogFileWriters.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:612)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2680)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:945)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:939)
    at claszzName2.spark.adaptor.utils.SparkUtils.newSparkSession(SparkUtils.java:42)
    at claszzName2.spark.adaptor.bqtopubsub.BqToPubSubAdaptor.main(BqToPubSubAdaptor.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
22/09/02 05:30:57 INFO org.sparkproject.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Stopped Spark@2db33feb{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:0}
22/09/02 05:30:58 ERROR clazzName: Spark Batch Application failed : {}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File not found: gs://temp-bucket/f80f8cb3-0358-445e-8ec2-819e4282bfe4/spark-job-history
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getFileStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.EventLogFileWriter.requireLogBaseDirAsDirectory(EventLogFileWriters.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.history.SingleEventLogFileWriter.start(EventLogFileWriters.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:612)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2680)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:945)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:939)
    at claszzName2.spark.adaptor.utils.SparkUtils.newSparkSession(SparkUtils.java:42)
    at claszzName2.spark.adaptor.bqtopubsub.BqToPubSubAdaptor.main(BqToPubSubAdaptor.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException
    at clazzName.main(BqToPubSubAdaptor.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.spark) Job [d8c3e7e5e8004e5bba72b921d454bfeb] failed with error:
Google Cloud Dataproc Agent reports job failure. If logs are available, they can be found at:
```

Comment: Have you hardcoded the path of eventlog in spark?Try changing the path to different one

Comment: How to check the existing path for eventlog in spark?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/jobs/history-server#set_up_a_job_cluster  --properties=spark:spark.history.fs.logDirectory=gs://bucket-name/*/spark-job-history 

--properties=mapred:mapreduce.jobhistory.read-only.dir-pattern=gs://bucket-name/*/mapreduce-job-history/done

Comment: The job would have run the first time. But seems it's failing since 2nd run. Most likely there is already an event history

Comment: Pls check this too-spark.eventLog.dir

Comment: @Subash Do you want me to add these two properties while running the job, will replace the bucket name.

Comment: I am not sure if the config files in the submit command have these properties. But you can try overriding these

Comment: Also next time before submitting queries please post the configuration details.It will help to debug faster

Comment: Is there any specific config you are looking for? I can try adding that in the question.

Comment: @Subash I have already added error log and spark job details in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247751/discussion-between-subash-and-aditya-mahajan).

Answer (score 0):

It seems GCP DataProc/spark is looking for default history server for event logging, which may not be located at specific location.
You can override two properties to update the logs location for history server.

- spark.eventLog.dir
- spark.history.fs.logDirectory

Either you can use these properties during submit of spark job, just like mentioned in example or you can update your spark-defaults.conf file
with these 2 properties.

Like

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
--cluster=clusterName \
--class=clazzName \
--jars=gs://abc/def/ghi.jar \
--region=us-central1 \
--files=gs://abc/def/jkl.json \
--properties=spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file=application_dev.json",spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dconfig.file=application_dev.json",spark.executor.memory=6G,spark.driver.memory=4G,spark.executor.cores=3,spark.executor.instances=4,spark.history.fs.logDirectory=gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>,spark.eventLog.dir=gs://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>
```